# How can I convert an Android Live Wallpaper to a watch face for Wear?

Tags: libgdx, wear-os, live-wallpaper

I developed an app (with libgdx) that includes a live wallpaper (LWP). Now I would like to port, convert or at least reuse part of the LWP to obtain a watch face for Android Wear. I've read a couple of times that a wear watch face is derived from the wallpaper service and that a LWP can be ported to wear, but so far I couldn't find any explanation as to how this can be achieved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Do the old Cut-n-Paste**

I had read that too. But that was before the SDK was released--that was a long time ago.  I would recommend:

- Get an example Android Wear program running (Use Android Studio)
- Move one section of code from your live-wallpaper to the Wear program
- Build it and hand-test it (hold off on the unit tests for now)
- And repeat with another bit of code until it is converted.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Keith for your answer. The problem ist that I made my live-wallpaper with libgdx. So I guess I cannot just copy that code to the Wear module - or am I missing something?

Comment: I have not done it myself, but others have used libgdx on AndroidWear. The Live-wallpaper to watch-face is not a straight copy, you will need to rewrite code. I think you can do it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I hope someone reading this has an example for libdgx on Android Wear watch faces.

Answer (score 1):

I have create a new libGDX android backend to support wear os watch face and submitted [a PR](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/5909). Unfortunately it was not merged but you can still copy my code to your project to implement the watch face.

Comment: Thanks Chenhe, I will have a look and keep it in mind for a possible new project. Cheers!